# Oracle SQL Hierarchical Query

Tags: sql, oracle10g

I'm trying to construct an Oracle sql query so select only the latest child records within a table that has a heirarchy of records.

Some records in a table have a reference to a parent record (parent_id column) which is a reference to its id.   These child records may have children too.

I want to construct a query where only the latest child is taken (if it has one/any). 
e.g.

```
my_table
id  parent_id   name
111 null        'no parent'

222 null        'one child'
333 222

444 null        'two children'
555 444
666 555
```

So the desired resultset would be

```
select id from <query>  
111     
333 
666
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be achieved by using a sub query on the same table.

```
select a.id 
from my_table a 
where not exists 
    (select 1 
     from my_table b 
     where b.parent_id = a.id)
```